# What are the Oculi crafting recipes?

Tags: child-of-light

In the Oculi crafting menu there is a "Tip" button that shows some basic recipes:

[image]

According to the first recipe, any three Oculi of the same color and size can be crafted into an Oculi one size larger.

By the looks of the second crafting recipe, the two primary colored Oculi can be combined into a secondary colored Oculi of the same size.

What about the third recipe? Can any three different Oculi be combined together for a White oculi? Or do they have to be Red, Green and Blue or Magenta, Cyan and Yellow?

What are the other crafting recipes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Everything is auto-positioned by dot. Diamond's line style changed for higher contrast.

All reactions are one way and downwards. I've hidden the directional arrows because they are ugly and do not add any information once you know everything is one-way.

[image]

Comment: Since the graph is not directed (i.e. no arrows to indicate direction), I assume the process is reversible (e.g., it's possible to get an emerald by combining a citrine and tourmaline.)?

Comment: No, that doesn't work, not that you'd want to.

Comment: @deutschZuid I've further clarified the answer so avoid future misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a full write up [here](http://www.flamingzonkey.com/child-of-light-oculi-crafting-and-effects-guide/), but in order to not be a link spammer...

Any three of the same oculi will give you a single one of the next tier better (Rough -> Tumbled -> Faceted -> Brilliant).

You can combine different colors of the same tier to get a single oculi of a different color of the same tier:

- Ruby + Sapphire = Amethyst
- Sapphire + Emerald = Tourmaline
- Ruby + Emerald = Citrine
- Sapphire + Ruby + Emerald = Diamond

From there, you can combine some of those into yet another type:

- Amethyst + Citrine + Tourmaline = Onyx

And then finally you can do one more combination:

- Diamond + Onyx = Spinel

I'm still working on gathering up all the different effects. Each of those types have three possible effects (depending on the slot you put them in), and the effects both amplify and can be slightly different between tiers.

Answer (score 2):

Spinel + Onyx + Diamond (Has to be Brilliant Tier) craft into the "Princess Stone," which is one of the best (if not the best) oculi in the game for the weapon and armor.